# javascript validation in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting this validation to work. I am validating that a selectbox has been chosen and not left on the default option within my form.

**Form:**

```
<label for="reason">How can we help?</label>
   <select name="reas">
    <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
        <option value="branding">Branding</option>
        <option value="rwd">Responsive Web Design</option><span id="dropdown_error"></span>
  </select>
```

**Onclick event:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(){
        return checkSelect();
    });
});
```

**Function:**

```
function checkSelect() {
    var chosen = "";
var len = document.conform.reas.length;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (document.conform.reas[i].selected){
            chosen = document.conform.reas[i].value;
        }
 }

    if (chosen == "Please Select") {
    document.getElementById("dropdown_error").innerHTML = "No Option Chosen";
        return false;
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("dropdown_error").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
    }
}
```

I also get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

I am really new to javascript, so, I am learning and trying some simple examples at the moment, but I cannot see what is causing this not to validate.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is there an error in the browser's JavaScript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't have your error span *inside* the `<select>`. Move it outside of the `<select>` HTML, and that will make the JS error go away.

```
<label for="reason">How can we help?</label>
<select name="reas">
    <option value="select">Please Select</option>
    <option vlaue="Web Design">Web Design</option>
    <option vlaue="branding">Branding</option>
    <option vlaue="rwd">Responsive Web Design</option>
</select>
<span id="dropdown_error"></span>
```

Then, since you are already using jQuery, you could shorten your whole validation function to just this:

```
function checkSelect() {
    var chosen = $('select[name="reas"]').val();
    if (chosen == "select") {
        $("dropdown_error").text("No Option Chosen");
        return false;
    } else {
        $("dropdown_error").text("");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you cory, misplaced the span like you said, thanks for the jquery alternative, need to get a bit more familiar with javascript first but definitely good to know

Answer (score 1):

Your default value is "select" and you are checking "Please Select". Use the same value.

Change this

```
<option value="select">Please Select</option>
```

to

```
<option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
```

EDIT: I would use the following code. To fix javascript issue, make sure you put the script just before closing body tag. Your script is executing before the document is parsed

```
<label for="reason">How can we help?</label>

<select id="reas" name="reas">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option vlaue="Web Design">Web Design</option>
    <option vlaue="branding">Branding</option>
    <option vlaue="rwd">Responsive Web Design</option><span id="dropdown_error">    </span>  </option>
```

```
function checkSelect() {
    var chosen = document.getElementById["reas"].value;


    if (chosen == "") {
        document.getElementById("dropdown_error").innerHTML = "No Option Chosen";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("dropdown_error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks jonas, but Cory has provided the correct answer, span was in wrong place and the please select default value as you stated

Answer (score 1):

Change your default selection to an `optgroup`:

```
<optgroup>Please Select</optgroup>
```

Then it won't be selectable

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: Ah brilliant, I will definitely use this in a live environment, but I wanted to do some exercises with javascript as I am learning it at the moment. albeit not very well